# Angular JS how to pass value from rootscope into ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, rootscope

I have object into rootscope and i would like to display some values in form inputs.

I tried following:

```
  <input type="number" ng-model="$root.order.id"  class="form-control" id="orderNumber" />
```

But this is not working.

How i should pass value into ng-model?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

No need of attach de $root to the variable, the flow of scope in angular is first search in the local scope for the variable, if not found search the property in $scope.parent, and the rootScope if the high level of parent if not match with any else, then search there.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3ENyPRwrFq5ssR2uLtQy

In this plnkr look the usage of the root scope

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.varRoot = {
    element: "Jesús"
  };
}]
);
```

HTML:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{varRoot.element}}!</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="varRoot.element">
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the name, ex:

```
$rootScope.order.id = 3;

<input type="number" ng-model="order.id"  class="form-control" id="orderNumber" />
```